# Quicken Best Practices for properly documenting my mortgage in Quicken when the lenders keep passing my mortage around?

Tags: mortgage, quicken

My Mortgage keeps getting passed around between lenders and this was fine the first 3 times it happened in 4 years; but the fourth time, they shifted me to a lender that doesn't support Quicken, and now my transactions are all out of sync.

They've been passing my mortgage around like it's a joint in a high school bathroom in the 70s.

I want to know what is going on with my Mortgage in case Pass and Puff Trust, loses their data and I don't have anything to back up my end of the case with about how much money I already paid into this mess.

Comment: How would your Quicken records prove anything about the money if they lose the records? You could have just made up numbers and typed them into your computer. Do they give you receipts?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is keep hardcopy of all statements for at least seven years, possibly for the life of the loan. If you don't have that, the current bank may be able to print their portion of it for you, or you may be able to print it from their website.

If you can't download and reconcile automatically in Quicken, you can review and reconcile manually against that/those printed statement(s). That's what we used to do before download was possible, and it's still what we do under these circumstances. Quicken still has functionality to help with this; see its help screens re reconciling.

Comment: There is more to this.  What about the loan account in quicken, and being able to deduct from it on all the different lenders?

No, my home is not large or spacious, for one I live in the USA, second I'm a Millennial.

Comment: See Quicken instructions for setting up loan accounts. If the loan gets sold, I think you can just treat it as a no-fee refinance at the same rate, using the "new loan" to pay off the old one.

Comment: Okay that sounds like some good advice.